# Redirect user to login page in the controllers method if else block - Rails 4, Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to be able to redirect a guest user to a Devise signin/login page after he/she clicked some links for 5 times. I counted clicks and I have else block where I am supposed to redirect guest to a sign up page but nothing happens. 
Log says:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-21 14:06:58 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
Rendered /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview2/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb (3.6ms)
Rendered /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview2/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (18.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 49ms
```

But I don't get redirected anywhere. Is there a way to do this?

Controller method count:

```
def count
 user = guest_user
  if ( params[:first_link] || params[:second_link] )
    user.increment!(:counter)
  else
   redirect_to new_user_session_url # this is the problem
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

```
function count(link_id) {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   format: 'json',
   url: '/count/' + link_id,
   success: function(data) { 
    if (data.counter == 5) {
      document.location.href = 'new_user_session_path';
    }
   }
  });
  return false;
}
```

And the error I get is: 
    No route matches [GET] "/new_user_session_path" 
but the route is actually there:
    new_user_session_path    GET     /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new

Comment: You should do it with JavaScript, not with HTTP redirect status.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with the JS problem I have.

Comment: Ok, check my answer now. It should help, I guess.

Comment: And? Did you try my solution?

Comment: I just did and getting a Bad Request error. Any ideas?

Comment: Paste relevant fragment of logs.

Comment: Nothing relevant in logs, only this:                                    Started GET "/count/link_id" for 127.0.0.1
Processing by Controller#count as */*
  Parameters: {"link_id"=>"link1"}
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 40]]
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
!! Invalid request

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the `counter` anywhere, you could do something like this:

```
def count
 user = guest_user
  if user.counter == 5                 # Assuming that you have counter property on User   
    user.counter = 0                   # reset the counter  
    redirect_to new_user_session_url **#this is the problem**
  else
    if ( params[:first_link] || params[:second_link] )
      user.increment!(:counter)
    end
  end
end
```

**BUT** As Marek suggested, you should think about resolving this on client side using `JavaScript` rather than making server calls.

Comment: Thanks, I did check counter as you said but didn't include it here. I tried with JavaScript but I am getting a routing error. Will update my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
document.location.href = 'new_user_session_path';
```

You should have:

```
document.location.href = '<%= new_user_session_path -%>';
```

This way, Rails will automatically generate proper URL for you using `new_user_session_path` helper.